# How to handle silverlight stackpanel mousemove event in windows 8?

Tags: silverlight

I am working on image slider functionality in windows 8?in silverlight there is an event mousemove event but in windows 8 not having that event?any one tell me equivalent mousemove event in windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

use the `GestureRecognizer`
here is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241937.aspx